# How to avoid infinite __eq__ recursion when class member contains other members of the same class

Tags: python, recursion

I need to match objects to objects and thus tried to encapsulate the data of the objects and the list of other objects that are a good match based on a certain criteria.

I wanted to write a custom *dunder eq* function to be able to compare my class based on value, so  if the data and the objects that they are matched with are both the same, then the two instances would be equal.

My class:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.matched_to = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Value: {}, Matches: {}".format(self.value, self.matched_to)

    def add_match(self, other: 'Data'):
        self.matched_to.append(other)

    def __eq__(self, other: 'Data'):
        if type(self) != type(other):
            return NotImplemented

        if self.value != other.value:
            return False

        for self_match, other_match in zip(self.matched_to, other.matched_to):
            if self_match != other_match:
                return False

        return True

elem1 = Data(10)
elem2 = Data(10)
elem3 = Data(10)

elem1.add_match(elem2)
elem2.add_match(elem1)
elem3.add_match(elem1)

print(elem1 == elem2)  # False as the value are the same but not the match up
print(elem2 == elem3)  # True as the value and matches are the same
```

And the terminal output is:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

My first solution to this problem was to separate the match container and the data, but I encountered the same problem as my class member would still contain members of the same class.

My second idea was to compare the matched objects based on their `id()` as in the following code. However, I feel like that beats the whole purpose of the custom equality and then I should just simply check the *id* of the `Data` members from the beginning (thus not implementing a custom dunder eq)

```
def __eq__(self, other: 'Data'):
        if type(self) != type(other):
            return NotImplemented

        if self.value != other.value:
            return False

        for self_match, other_match in zip(self.matched_to, other.matched_to):
            if id(self_match) != id(other_match):
                return False

        return True
```

What would be the best way to solve this design flaw of mine? Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that objects contain objects of the same type, it's that you have *cycles*: elem1 contains elem2 and elem2 contains elem1, so it's not possible to resolve recursive operations because there is no terminal case to your recursion.

Don't do cycles if you intend to recurse.

Comment: But for my use case it make sense. Let's say I have two bounding boxes that have  the same coordinates. The first would be a match to the second and the second would be match to the first.

Comment: Then you can't use __eq__, you have to use some other external equivalence function which can take in account cycles.

Answer (score 0):

For you understanding, your code is similar to:

```
l1 = []
l2 = []
l1.append(l2)
l2.append(l1)
l1 == l2
```

you receive same error `maximum recursion depth exceeded`